# hdfs connection error from scala

Tags: scala, maven, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I am new to hadoop, just started and trying to connect to hdfs using scala and spark, but no idea what is wrong with the configuration. Please help me resolve and understand it.

```
Hadoop Version is 2.7.3
Scala Version is 2.12.1
Spark Version is 2.1.1
```

**pom.xml (dependencies)**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

**scala code base**

```
object SparkHDFS {
  def getDataFromHdfs {
    val hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://localhost:9000"), new Configuration)
    val file = new Path("rdd/insurance.csv")
    val stream = hdfs open file
    println(stream.readLine())
  }

  def main(arr: Array[String]) {
    getDataFromHdfs
  }
}
```

**Exception on console:**

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:2400)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2411)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2428)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:367)
    at com.sample.sparkscala.SparkHDFS$.getDataFromHdfs(SparkHDFS.scala:11)
    at com.sample.sparkscala.SparkHDFS$.main(SparkHDFS.scala:18)
    at com.sample.sparkscala.SparkHDFS.main(SparkHDFS.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration$DeprecationDelta
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.HdfsConfiguration.addDeprecatedKeys(HdfsConfiguration.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.HdfsConfiguration.<clinit>(HdfsConfiguration.java:31)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.<clinit>(DistributedFileSystem.java:116)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration$DeprecationDelta
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Have you triggered ur scala code from eclipse??

Try to make a jar out of it; and submit as `hadoop jar ...` command.

That way, it will get all hadoop related lib jars from classpath.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you read the files in spark. Spark provides inbuilt support for csv files.

Follow some tutorials on reading files from hdfs in spark.

Here is simple example of reading csv files in spark

```
val df = spark.read
        .format("csv")
        .option("header", "true") //reading the headers
        .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
        .csv(""hdfs://localhost:9000")
```

You also need to use scala 2.11.x and not 2.12.x

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is "spark" an object of spark context, If yes, I am getting compile time error, it says "read" is not a member of org.apache.spark.SparkContext.

Comment: Can you suggest me some pages from where I may get info regarding spark hdfs connection.

Comment: spark is the object of SparkSession   val spark =
    SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("test").getOrCreate()

Comment: Your command stores the file in a dataframe whereas OP is trying to read the file and print it to stdout.